# Two partitions mounted on the same mountpoint

Tags: linux, mount

We noticed 2 partitions mounted on the same mount point.
In altering and creating files seems to be everything normal, even the inode usage are the same.

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)

uname -r
2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64

df -hT /mydir
Filesystem           Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/STG-MYDIR
                     ext4   30G   10G   18G  34% /mydir
```

Here is possible to see that situation:

```
df -hT | grep -B 1 mydir
/dev/mapper/STG2-MYDIR
                     xfs     30G   10G   18G  34% /mydir
--
/dev/mapper/STG-MYDIR
                     ext4    30G   10G   18G  34% /mydir
```

**Do I risk data loss or data corruption?**

Answer (score 1):

Actually the last partition is mounted and being used, and if you unmount it then the first one will be mounted. No risk of data loss but it's unnecessary because only the last one mounted is being used.